# Unexplained and unintentional mirroring behaviour of vertices with various actions

Tags: mirror

I think I might have messed up some setting. The latest example was when attempting to subdivide an extruded rectangle.
The first subdivision went okay.

[image: Selection of the first edge for subdivision]
Selection of the first edge for subdivision

[image: Vertex selection after subdivision]
Vertex selection after subdivision

[image: Moved vertex without problem]
Moved vertex without problem

[image: Edge select for cut 2]
Edge select for cut 2

[image: Vertex selection after subdivision of second edge]
Vertex selection after subdivision of second edge

[image: As soon as I attempted to move this vertex, the first went flying]
As soon as I attempted to move this vertex, the first went flying

At this point any attempt at moving either vertex resulted in a type of mirrored movement of the unselected vertex. Even crazier examples happen when certain objects are moved. I have reloaded Blender.app, tried backups and was unsuccessful in finding the cause.
Thanks, TOM

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the nudge in the right direction. After much searching I found that X Mirror had been enabled in the options tab. Hope this goof can help others. TOM

[image]